# The meaning of the word "Yet"

Tags: grammar

It is quite confusing every time I see the word "yet" placed at the start or middle of a sentence or phrase.

For example: (Copy from somewhere)

> Here is a very simple, ***yet*** attractive, list of basic English words.

As far as I know, the word "YET" should perform like this:

> ***Not yet***, I'm still working on it.

In this case, ***YET*** means something is in progress.

Does the word ***YET*** have any other functions?

Comment: Have you consulted a dictionary?

Comment: @stoneyB I did, but I still don't know clearly.

Comment: Those are two entirely different meanings.  The first means basically "but".  The second means "up to this time".  If you consult a dictionary you will notice that even the most limited one specifies at least 3 distinct definitions.

Comment: There are far more than two different meanings. For instance _yet more_ means _still/even more_; and _nor yet_ means 'and also not'. And those aren't even the time-related meanings. These little words are worth looking up in the OED because it gives you a good sense of how long they've been around and how many little jobs they've been doing.

Comment: Not yet, yet I'm still working on it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yet can be used in the way you're describing (an adverb), but it also has a different meaning that is taken on when it is used as a *conjunction*.

Yet via [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/yet)

> though; still; nevertheless: "The essay is good, yet it could be improved."

In your example sentence, they give an arguably disparaging adjective (simple) to describe a person, and then counter it with *yet* and follow with a positive adjective (attractive) to denote *in spite of/despite* simplicity or attractiveness *counteracting the negativity of* simplicity.

In this way, you could use it as a counterexample for someone who has a quality that would not be expected with another quality ("A silly man yet quite poetic at times"), or a presentation of a positive and negative quality ("A simple yet attractive woman", "A  sloven yet compassionate husband").

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is yes. The word "yet" has multiple functions. It can be used as both an adverb and a conjunction. Both of your example sentences use it as an adverb.

In your first example sentence, the applicable definition of "yet" is "even; still (used to emphasize a comparative)." This is the seventh definition on Dictionary.com.

In your second example sentence, the applicable definition of "yet" is "at the present time; now." This is the first definition on Dictionary.com.

Here is the link to dictionary.com's entry for "yet." It's understandable that you could be confused about this word; it has a lot of different definitions. Hopefully, looking at its dictionary listing will clear it up for you.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/yet